# Unable to access array data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am still very new to programming and javascript. The problem I am facing now is I am not able to access the data inside array.
Here is my code snippet

```
global.arr = [];
var id = 12;

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
   arr.push(id);
   id++;
}
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0]);
```

[image: this is the console image]

My question is that, how can I access into the data and what did i do wrong here?

---

Here is the code I currently have, it still doesn't seem to work:

```
var arr = [];
var id = 12;

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
   arr.push(id);
   id++;
}
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Comment: Is `global === window`?

Comment: people stop downvoting questions just because people are new to programming!

Comment: @Luke Please stop assuming the reasons people downvote.

Comment: Not is necessary use "global"

Comment: @Luke No one is down voting just because people are new to programming, they down vote bad questions, no matter if you have a rep. of 1 or 100000.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: Expanding this a little more:

`global` is not a JavaScript object. There are *[global objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects)*, but you access them through `window` not `global`. Your code would only work if you had, somewhere else, set `global` equal to `window`.

Unless you have a really good reason to use `global` (or `window` for that matter), just define the array (and other variables) with `var` or `let`.

```js
let arr = [];
let id = 12;

for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
   arr.push(id);
   id++;
}
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had changed to declare as var, however I am still getting the same problem, the output is still undefined...

Comment: @Emilylaw In that case, please copy the code you tried just now and add it as an Edit to your question!

Comment: @Emilylaw The updated code in your question seems to work just fine now: https://jsfiddle.net/cngv0fqp/

Answer (score 2):

I believe `global` is the root of your issue. It works when in the browser and using `window`

```js
window.arr = [];
var id = 12;

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
   arr.push(id);
   id++;
}
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0]);
```

However, it is better to not set directly to the `window` and instead use `var arr = []` or `let arr = []`

Comment: i would not suggest to use a global variable like "window". as you read, he is new to programming. i think it would be good to improve his thinking

Comment: I didn't "suggest" anything – just stated "global" is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

To a global array you don't need to set

```
global.arr = [];
```

Just set a let variable:

```
let arr = [];
var id = 12;
```

See: [Let](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Then use your code:

```js
let arr = [];
var id = 12;

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
 arr.push(id);
 id++;
}
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

A variable declared outside a function, becomes GLOBAL.
you can declare the variable arr.

```js
var arr = [];
var id = 12;
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
   arr.push(id);
   id++;
}
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0]);
```